# What is the most "elegant" way to define a global constant array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, constants, global

I was wondering what do you think would be the best and cleanest way to define a constant array variable similar to the way **define** function works. I've seen a lot of people asking this question in Google and so far the easiest solution I have come up with is to use the PHP **serialize** function inside the **define** statement, like this

```
define ("MY_ARRAY", serialize (array ("key1" => $value1,"key2" => $value2, ..)));
```

then to use the defined constant you can do something like this:

```
$MY_ARRAY = unserialize (MY_ARRAY)
print_r ($MY_ARRAY);
```

Not sure if the **serialize** function will slow you down if you have a lot of **defines** in your code. What do you think?

Comment: What do you need the global var for. Perhaps there is a better approach.

Comment: $GLOBALS['MY_ARRAY'] = array();

Comment: PeeHaa, I would need it to be global if I wanted to access the constant array from within any class or function in the same namespace!

Comment: dqhendricks - your solution is very attractive, but don't you always have ot use the $GLOBALS['MY_ARRAY'] whenever you want to access it? Also, is $GLOBALS also constant? I think not!

Comment: $GLOBALS is a super global available in every part of your code, much like $_POST or $_GET. Although you are right, it is not truely a constant. PHP does not allow for constant arrays.

Comment: yes you would have to use $GLOBALS['MY_ARRAY'] whenever you want to access it, but at least you don't have to deserialize.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$GLOBALS['MY_ARRAY'] = array();
```

Comment: Can somebody override MY_ARRAY with $_POST["MY_ARRAY"} or $_GET["MY_ARRAY"] and inject their own code this way?

Comment: no, that is why the super global arrays were invented. back in the olden days people used to set it in the PHP config so that post variables became global variables, until they realised that this was a hackers dream. to be sure, try it out on your test server and see what happens.

Comment: $GLOBALS is not related in any way to the $_POST or $_GET variables.

Comment: does **define** also make a variable "superglobal"?

Comment: well, it would be related, if you're on an evil evil host that still has register_globals enabled. But otherwise, yes, they're completely seperate.

Comment: define just makes a global. superglobals never need to be defined in the first place.

Comment: This one does look clean and fairly easy to use, with the exceptions that: a) you have to use $GLOBALS everytime you want ot pass it to a function, like int call_function($GLOBALS['MY_ARRAY']) and b) it's not exactly contstant, but VOTE-UP for a really neat solution otherwise! Thank you! :)

Comment: you do NOT have to pass it to functions... the $GLOBALS array is available in EVERY part of your code at ALL times.

Comment: Well, it depends...I have a class that generates some objects based on the values specified in a constant array(val1, val2, val3) and I have a set of these arrays, each of which specifies a predefined object configuration, so I would have to pass each one of those arrays to the class constructor in order to generate multiple versions of those objects, based on the values specified in the arrays, in as clean way as I can. In this case I have to specify, which array I want to build the classes based on

Comment: .. by passing it to the constructor function, like in foo(ARRAY1), foo(ARRAY2), where foo is the class constructor

Comment: sounds like you should either be making subclasses that extend your class, or you can just pass the $GLOBALS key string, not the entire array contained at that key.

Comment: That is a good suggestion! After doing some testing with **$GLOBALS** & **define** I decided in favor of **define** for my application, because it would actually throw an error if you try to override the variable after it was already set. But I had to sacrifice some of the app speed in the process. I really like your solution too. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: BTW, I AM making subclasses, but in order for me to refer to them, I am using **define(OBJECT_ONE, serialize(array("class1" => "obj1_class1", "class2" => "obj1_class2", "class3" = "obj1_class3")));** Then my base class generates the instances of its children on the fly, but to do that I have to pass the defined variable to the **addChildren(OBJECT_ONE)** method, and then **addChildren(OBJECT_TWO)**, etc. Each object has different classes names from one another and the base class doesn't know how to refer to them otherwise, hense the **define()**. It works! Hope I didn't confuse you too much :)

Answer (score 6):

The serialization and especially unserialization is pretty awkward. (On the other hand it's not quite clear why a scripting language can't have arrays as constants...)

But it really depends on the usage pattern. Normally you want global defines for storing configuration settings. And global variables and constant are an appropriate use for that (despite the "globals are evil!!1!" meme). But it's advisable to throw everything into some sort of registry object or array at least:

```
class config {
     var $MY_ARRAY = array("key1"=>...);
     var $data_dir = "/tmp/";
}
```

This gives the simplest access syntax with `config::$MY_ARRAY`. That's not quite an constant, but you can easily fake it. Just use an ArrayObject or ArrayAccess and implement it in a way to make the attributes read-only. (Make [offsetSet](http://www.php.net/manual/de/arrayaccess.offsetset.php) throw an error.)

If you want a global array constant workaround, then another alternative (I've stolen this idea from the [define manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)) is to use a function in lieu of a constant:

```
function MY_ARRAY() {
     return array("key1" => $value1,);
}
```

The access is again not quite constantish, but `MY_ARRAY()` is short enough. Though the nice array access with `MY_ARRAY()["key1"]` is not possible prior PHP 5.3; but again this could be faked with `MY_ARRAY("key1")` for example.

Comment: Mario, what can, potentially, go wrong with the serialization? Also, neither the function or the class would go into the global scope.

Comment: @techexpert, there is nothing wrong with serialization really. But `unserialize(MY_ARRAY)` reads pretty lengthy, and you always need a temporary variable for unpacking. This kind of defeats the purpose of easy to access constants. You might as well define a function `my_const_array("NAME")` to get it from a registry.

Comment: I really wanted to find an alternative to the "define" statement for arrays, so you can pass the variable to any function in a clean way, like: call_function(MY_ARRAY)

Comment: I'd say the same 2 exceptions, that I pointed out to dqhendricks answer, apply here, but also VOTE-UP for a neat answer!!! Thank you! ;)

Comment: Tested it and it does not work (am I missing something?):
class MyClass {
    var $test = array('foo', 'bar');
}
echo MyClass::$test;
(tried here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/:)