# PHP Constants with variables

Tags: php

I know this is probably a newbie question, but is it possible to do this?

```
unserialize(LOG_ACTIONS_.''.strtoupper($language));
```

I have list of constants with _LANGUAGE which I want to use the variable $language with.

Example:

```
unserialize(LOG_ACTIONS_ENGLISH);
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function LOG_ACTIONS_strtoupper()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`constant()`](http://php.net/constant) to get the constant's actual value.

```
unserialize(constant(LOG_ACTIONS_.''.strtoupper($language)));
```

I'm not sure whether having serialized data in a constant is really wise, though - it can be expensive if there's a lot of data in them.

I assume it's to circumvent the restriction that constants can't contain array values.  This SO question shows some better ways to work around that:

[What is the most "elegant" way to define a global constant array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637402/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-define-a-global-constant-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just use the [constant()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function:

```
unserialize(constant('LOG_ACTIONS_'.strtoupper($language)));
```